# Compile MatConvnet in matlab, got nvcc error : 'cicc' died with status 0xC0000005 (ACCESS_VIOLATION)

Tags: matlab

I'm using matlab r2018a with vs2017 community and cuda 9.0.
When I download the latest version of matconvnet and compile it using `vl_compilenn`  in matlab, I got nvcc error

```
0x00007FF64188ADD0 (0x0000000000000000 0x000001E56C1C7F18 0x000066BA00000001 0x00000004000304ED) 
0x00007FF641886F3D (0x0000009EBEFFE798 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000001E56C1DCE20) 
0x00007FF641888713 (0xnvcc warning : The -std=c++11 flag is not supported with the configured host compiler. Flag will be ignored. 
data.cu 
nvcc error   : 'cicc' died with status 0xC0000005 (ACCESS_VIOLATION) 
Error using vl_compilenn>nvcc_compile (line 615)
Command "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin\nvcc" -c -o
"D:\Matlab\matconvnet-1.0-beta25\matconvnet-1.0-beta25\matlab\mex\.build\bits\data.obj"
"D:\Matlab\matconvnet-1.0-beta25\matconvnet-1.0-beta25\matlab\src\bits\data.cu" -DENABLE_GPU -DENABLE_DOUBLE
-DENABLE_CUDNN -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\include" -O -DNDEBUG -D_FORCE_INLINES
--std=c++11 -I"D:\Matlab\extern\include" -I"D:\Matlab\toolbox\distcomp\gpu\extern\include"
-gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\"  --compiler-options=/MD --compiler-bindir="C:\Program
Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\bin"  failed.

Error in vl_compilenn (line 487)
      nvcc_compile(opts, srcs{i}, objfile, flags) ;
```

Any advice will be appreciated.